# Can't step into a DLL call

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, dll, clr

I have an unmanaged application, "A", which exhibits strange behavior during runtime. "A" is an MSVC++ project (with no CLR support) which makes calls to a DLL project, "B". "B" is another MSVC++ project that has CLR support in it:

```
void LoggerPost(DWORD dwSeverity, LPTSTR szAppID, LPTSTR szMsgString)
{
    UnmanagedLoggerClient::LogMessage(dwSeverity, szAppID, "", szMsgString);
}
```

The above method, called from "A", calls the LogMessage function in "B". This call works at first, but as time goes on and the method gets called more frequently on this DLL, and eventually, calls to this method stop returning. As a result, I was trying to find out if there was a deadlock in the LogMessage method. I tried debugging into project "A" by attaching the debugger to it. To my surprise, **I found out that stepping into the LogMessage function does not work**! I can't seem to step into it. I have the PDB's for both projects in the same directory, and I made sure that the debugging option for "Just My Code" was off, but to no avail. Now I am trying to figure out what to do to break into this method call on runtime...any ideas?

Comment: Have you enabled mixed-mode debugging? You might have to force VS into that mode if you're going Native -> CLR, I've run into that issue before.

Comment: Is your MSVC 2013? In my situation, the CLR program can been steped into from native probgram in MSVC 2012 but not MSVC2013. And in my memory(not sure), if the MSVC2013 CLR program is /clr, it cannot been stepped into, while /clr:pure can.

Comment: @TimoGeusch By setting Mixed as the Debugging option in the project's properties page before compiling?

Comment: @cbel The Platform Toolset is 2013, and I am using VS2013, is this what you are referring to? I will try /clr:pure.

Comment: @Alexandru, yes, but you just need to set it before debugging, it's not needed for compilation.

Comment: @TimoGeusch I tried but it doesn't seem to want to work. I will try the /clr:pure option...you're sure that to enable it its just a project setting change, not a debugger option, right?

Comment: @TimoGeusch Do you know if the CLR project also needs this setting? ...may be why its not working for me.

Comment: OKAY! I got it debugging into it! ...WHEN ATTACHING THE DEBUGGER, I HAD TO ENABLE BOTH NATIVE, AND MANAGED 4.5, AND ALSO...THE TRICK: MANAGED COMPATABILITY MODE...I didn't need to use /clr:pure here, thankfully, because that has more restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When attaching the debugger (Debug -> Attach to Process), where it says "Attach to:" I had to hit the "Select..." button -> check off "Debug these code types:" -> select Managed (v4.5, v4.0), Native, and Managed Compatability Mode, and then attach to the process in order to be able to debug through its calls.